# joining 2 df gives higher amount of visits than original data frame

Tags: r

I want to join  2 data frames, on the date_final and rubro columns.... I want the final df to have visits and transaction by date_final. If there is a date that does not have a visit, but a transaction, the visit should be NA. Same case when there is a visit and no transaction, the transaction should be NA.

I've tried:

```
df <- full_join(ene_visitas, ene_tx, by = c("date_final" = "date_final", "rubro" = "rubro"))
```

but the total visits amount is higher than original. Why could this happen?

ene_visitas:

```
ene_visitas<- structure(list(date_final = c(20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521), 
    i_unidad = c("VD", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "MX", 
    "MX", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", 
    "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "DA", "MX", "MX", 
    "MX", "MX", "VD", "VD", "VD", "VD", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", 
    "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", 
    "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", 
    "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", 
    "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", "VD", "VD", 
    "VD", "VD", "VD", "VD", "VD", "VD", "VD", "VD", "VD"), medio = c("Mailing", 
    "facebook", "facebook", "facebook", "google_search", "google_shopping", 
    "google_display", "google_search", "google_shopping", "Mailing", 
    "Directo", "Otros", "Organico", "Otros", "Otros", "Txt", 
    "Otros", "Mailing", "Otros", "Otros", "Organico", "Otros", 
    "Otros", "Mailing", "Otros", "Otros", "google_display", "YouTube", 
    "TikTok", "facebook", "google_search", "facebook", "google_shopping", 
    "google_display", "Txt", "Mailing", "Mailing", "Organico", 
    "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Directo", "Mailing", "Otros", 
    "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Mailing", "Otros", "Mailing", 
    "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Mailing", 
    "Mailing", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", 
    "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Mailing", "Otros", 
    "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "SS.com", "Organic", 
    "Directo", "Facebook Social", "Referral", "Txt", "S-Members", 
    "Push notifications", "VTEXCEM", "Otros", "SS.com.pe"), rubro = c("CDM - Mailing", 
    "Social Ads", "Social Ads", "Social Ads", "Search Ads", "Search Ads", 
    "Display Ads", "Search Ads", "Search Ads", "CDM - Mailing", 
    "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "CDM - SMS", 
    "Otros", "CDM - Mailing", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", 
    "Otros", "CDM - Mailing", "Otros", "Otros", "Display Ads", 
    "Online Video Ads", "Social Ads", "Social Ads", "Search Ads", 
    "Social Ads", "Search Ads", "Display Ads", "CDM - SMS", "CDM - Mailing", 
    "CDM - Mailing", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", 
    "CDM - Mailing", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "CDM - Mailing", 
    "Otros", "CDM - Mailing", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", 
    "Otros", "Otros", "CDM - Mailing", "CDM - Mailing", "Otros", 
    "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", 
    "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "CDM - Mailing", "Otros", "Otros", 
    "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", 
    "Otros", "Otros", "CDM - SMS", "Otros", "CDM - Push", "Otros", 
    "Otros", "Otros"), tipo_de_fuente = c("No Paid", "Paid", 
    "Paid", "Paid", "Paid", "Paid", "Paid", "Paid", "Paid", "No Paid", 
    "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", 
    "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", 
    "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "Paid", "Paid", 
    "Paid", "Paid", "Paid", "Paid", "Paid", "Paid", "No Paid", 
    "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", 
    "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", 
    "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", 
    "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", 
    "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", 
    "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", 
    "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", 
    "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", 
    "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid"), visitas = c(434, 
    13, 10, 1199, 2107, 862, 75, 8149, 2352, 196, 144, 128, 109, 
    42, 22, 19, 10, 10, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 968, 59, 27, 
    17905, 1644, 1013, 924, 15, 5819, 2395, 1526, 1440, 1206, 
    844, 761, 692, 590, 250, 198, 194, 185, 119, 109, 53, 26, 
    23, 20, 13, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 284, 240, 210, 84, 21, 18, 16, 
    15, 3, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -87L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

ene_tx:

```
ene_tx <- structure(list(date_final = c(20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 
20220521, 20220521, 20220521, 20220521), i_unidad = c("DA", "MX", 
"VD", "MX", "DA", "MX", "DA", "DA", "DA", "MX", "MX", "MX", "MX", 
"MX", "VD"), medio = c("facebook", "facebook", "facebook", "google_display", 
"Mailing", "Mailing", "SMS", "vtex", "NA", "Push notifications", 
"S-Members", "SMS", "vtex", "NA", "NA"), rubro = c("Social Ads", 
"Social Ads", "Social Ads", "Display Ads", "CDM - Mailing", "CDM - Mailing", 
"CDM - SMS", "Otros", "Otros", "CDM - Push", "Otros", "CDM - SMS", 
"Otros", "Otros", "Otros"), tipo_de_fuente = c("Paid", "Paid", 
"Paid", "Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", 
"No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid", "No Paid"
), transacciones_vtex = c(2, 159, 1, 2, 1, 14, 1, 1, 9, 8, 5, 
21, 10, 179, 18)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You are joining on `date_final` and `rubro`, which together are not unique keys. For instance `ene_visitas` has 55  observations with 20220521-Otros, each of which can be paired with each of the 6 times that combination occurs in the first table. So your join will produce 55 x 6 = 330 lines representing the matching rows for that combination. You might do better adding `medio` and `i_unidad`, but that's still not quite unique, given for instance 8 appearances of 20220521/CDM - Mailing/Mailing/MX in the ene_visitas table.

Comment: @JonSpring I don't have a `unique keys` column. But I need transactions and visits next to each other, and should take into account date... is there any option?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get what you want if you first summarize your tables to have only one line per unique set of joinable data:

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(
  count(ene_visitas, date_final, i_unidad, medio, rubro, tipo_de_fuente, 
        wt = visitas, name = "visitas"),
  count(ene_tx,      date_final, i_unidad, medio, rubro, tipo_de_fuente,
        wt = transacciones_vtex, name = "transacciones_vtex"))-> ene_combi
```

We can verify this has the same total as the underlying tables:

```
summarize(ene_combi, across(c(visitas, transacciones_vtex), ~sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  visitas transacciones_vtex
    <dbl>              <dbl>
1   55958                431


count(ene_visitas, wt = visitas)
# A tibble: 1 × 1
      n
  <dbl>
1 55958


count(ene_tx, wt = transacciones_vtex)
# A tibble: 1 × 1
      n
  <dbl>
1   431
```